# Best way to replace column values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best way to such an operation:

```
data[col] = data[col].fillna(0)
```

I just want to replace the values of a column without raising the warning:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

Comment: 1/ show a [mcve] so that we can reproduce. 2/ follow the warning advice and use `loc`. Without more info about the code that raises the warning, I cannot say more...

Comment: well, did you try the suggestion?

Comment: A minimal reproducible example would be any pandas series.

Comment: The suggestion has a row_indexer, does not make sense in my case

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion works :

```
d = {'date': ['2020-01','2020-01','2020-02','2020-02','2020-03','2020-03','2020-04','2020-04',], 'A': [1,2,np.nan,4,5,6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
          date    A
0  2020-01  1.0
1  2020-01  2.0
2  2020-02  NaN
3  2020-02  4.0
4  2020-03  5.0
5  2020-03  6.0
6  2020-04  7.0
7  2020-04  8.0


df.loc[df['A'].isna(),'A']=0

print(df)

      date    A
0  2020-01  1.0
1  2020-01  2.0
2  2020-02  0.0
3  2020-02  4.0
4  2020-03  5.0
5  2020-03  6.0
6  2020-04  7.0
7  2020-04  8.0
```

Comment: What about a more generic problem, where you want to replace the column by a multiplication of 2 for instance?

Comment: df.loc[your condition,the column you want to replace]= your value. You can replace your value by df['A']*df['B']